# Laravel 5 `belongsToMany` with `wherePivot` eloquent query is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Suppose I have `users,courses` and `course_users` tables, users belongs to many courses and the structure of pivot table `course_users` is as bellow:

*| user_id | course_id | relation_type |*
*|-----------------------------------------------|*

now I have bellow code:

```
$user = User:find(1);
```

and I have bellow function in `user` model:

```
public function courses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Course')->wherePivot('relation_type', 1)->orWherePivot('relation_type', 0)->withPivot('relation_type', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
}
```

and if I want to get the course of user:

```
$user->courses();
```

But the output query of above function is like:

```
select 
  `courses`.*, `course_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`,`course_user`.`course_id` as `pivot_course_id`, 
  `course_user`.`relation_type` as `pivot_relation_type`,`course_user`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `course_user`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` 
from 
  `courses` inner join `course_user` on `courses`.`id` = `course_user`.`course_id` 
where 
  `course_user`.`user_id` = '1' and `course_user`.`relation_type` = '0' or `course_user`.`relation_type` = '1';
```

But I need to have something like this:

```
select 
   `courses`.*, `course_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `course_user`.`course_id` as `pivot_course_id`, 
   `course_user`.`relation_type` as `pivot_relation_type`, `course_user`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `course_user`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` 
from 
   `courses` inner join `course_user` on `courses`.`id` = `course_user`.`course_id` 
where 
   `course_user`.`user_id` = '1' and (`course_user`.`relation_type` = '0' or `course_user`.`relation_type` = '1');
```

The difference is in `where` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wherePivot` method on the relationship is just a shortcut for the `where` method, but it takes care of adding on the pivot table qualifier for the constraints. Because of this, it doesn't support closures, which is what you need to use in order to group your constraints. Therefore, you will need to call the `where` method directly, and manually add in the table name qualifier to your where conditions.

Something like:

```
public function courses() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Course')
        // pass a closure to group your constraints
        ->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('course_user.relation_type', 1)
                ->orWhere('course_user.relation_type', 0);
        })
        ->withPivot('relation_type', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
}
```